# water leak from ceiling

Tags: plumbing, water, waterproofing

I'm Ahammed Sheriff from Oman. Here we have a building with 6 floors. On the basement floor of the building there is leakage on the ceiling. Is there any way to stop the leakage from the ceiling? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'd really need more information to be able to help; what is above the leak? is this a recent thing? when does it get better or worse? is there any sort of odor?

Answer (score 4):

You must search for the source of this leak by inspecting the walls immediately above where you see water. In many cases like this you will see damp spot on the walls above and these must be cut open to inspect pipes for the  leak. If the walls are covered with gyproc or similar this is not a difficult job. Finding the leak is essential or it will destroy walls and flooring.